# iTunesConnect Start Testing operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

When I tried to upload one of my iOS app to iTunesConnect directly from Xcode 6.3.2, it validates correctly but fails to upload with error-

> The application you have selected doesn't exist.

So I tried to upload with application loader 3.1, I prepared IPA for AppStore distribution (beta testing enabled). Application loader can upload, but shows a warning like -

> The resulting API analysis file is too large.  We were unable to
>   validate your API usage prior to delivery.  This is just an
>   informational message.

But it uploads fine and iTunesConnect shows it.

Now I move under the TestFlight tab, select the latest version for beta testing. Then whenever I click on Start Testing, it simple says "operation_failed" with no other details.

I tried several times (reloaded browser and the page) and repeated the process. My Internal team is already set up and previous version of the application is already approved and live in iTunes.

Comment: I couldn't get the XCode working 3 days ago. And started to get the test flight operation failed from yesterday.

Comment: @GraceShao you are correct. I waited one day and it's working now. Thanks.